# Laravel Artisan Loading from Wrong project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Sorry if this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer. I have a Laravel 5.5 application that lets users create their own project. What this does is it executes a shell script that performs a git clone to a new directory

> - cd to the new git directory
> - update the .env db details to new directory (db_dirname)
> - run composer install
> - php artisan key:generate
> - php artisan migrate --seed

The problem I'm having is that when I run this using...

```
sh project1/public/createproject.sh subdir
```

It runs as expected however when running this from PHP the `php artisan` commands are running against the current project rather than the project that is being dynamically created.

```
 // Create the Git pull migration script
 $process = new Process('sh ./createproject.sh '.$this->url);
 $process->setTimeout(300);
 $process->run();

 // Executes after the command finishes
 if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
     throw new ProcessFailedException($process3);
 }

 \Log::Debug($process->getOutput());
```

The shell script is below for reference.

```
SUBDOMAIN="$1.domain.com"
git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/project.git
cd /home/cloudspr/$SUBDOMAIN
export COMPOSER_HOME="/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer"
composer install -d /home/user/$SUBDOMAIN
pwd
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate --seed --database=mysql
grep APP_KEY .env
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have trouble selecting the right working directory.

A couple if ideas come to mind:

1. Edit the bash script to point directly to the artisan file you are targeting:

   php /home/user/project.../artisan key:generate
2. Try changing the working directory before executing the script like this:

   $process = new Process('cd new/working/directory && sh ./createproject.sh '.$this->url);
3. Use [chdir](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)